# Does it make sense to multithread std::filesystem::exists calls?

Tags: c++

Hello I have the following scenario:

I have a `std::map` on the form `<std::string, std::vector<uint8_t>>` for each key-value pair in the map. I need to identify if a file on disk already exists with the name of the `key` otherwise I need to store the `value` on disk in a file with the name `key`. Right now what I do is:

```
std::vector<std::string> bases_to_stor(std::map<std::string,
                                                std::vector<uint8_t>>& input)
{
    std::vector<std::string> hashes; 

    for (std::map<std::string, std::vector<uint8_t>>::iterator it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (!std::filesystem::exists(it->first))
        {
            bool hash_in_hashes = false;
            for (const auto elm : hashes)
            {
                if (elm == it->first)
                {
                    hash_hashes = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!hash_in_hashes)
            {
                hashes.push_back(it->first); 
            }
        }
    }
    return hashes; 
}
```

But the size of `input` can be CRAZY big, +10k entries, and therefore I was thinking to make the `exists` call in multiple threads. But is that a benefit? Can the exists call be done in parallel? I have been unable to find information about this in the C++ standard and unable to identify if this is support by the underlying filesystem, EXT4 and ZFS, so I need some enlightenment on this.

Comment: This will depend heavily on a multitude of factors, filesystem type, whether the system has cached some of that data and so on. Exists calls can be expensive so it makes sense to not have them on your main thread if you have a gui application for instance.

Comment: Aside: `std::map` guarantees uniqueness (and order) of it's key element. You don't have to check `hashes` for `it->first` (see also [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no problem doing multiple `exists` calls in parallel. The OS certainly supports it (it's a multiuser OS, after all) and the C++ standard doesn't define it as a race condition. (There are potential race conditions associated with interleaved R/W access to files, but `exists` is read-only.)

It's a tossup whether it'll give you much of a speedup, though. Pipelining IO is a common optimization, but it makes the most sense for independent latency-bound resources like network sockets. If all the requests are going to the same disk, you're likely to saturate the bandwidth pretty quickly. (Though as Moeren mentioned, keeping those calls off the main thread is a good idea if you have a UI to keep responsive.)

Of course, if the number of potentially relevant files on disk is smaller than the number of files you're looking for, it would be better to enumerate those and check each one against the map, rather than the other way around.